# Access function scope chain from a globally defined function

Tags: javascript, closures, scope

```
function globalFunc1() {
  console.log(hello);
}

function globalFunc2() {
  var hello = 'hello';
  globalFunc1(); // expected to print "hello" but `hello` is undefined instead
}

globalFunc2();
```

Would that be possible without passing the inner variable(s) to `globalFunc1()`?
I am currently using the following hack to achieve what I want but it's way too hackish and inelegant.

```
function globalFunc2() {
  var hello = 'hello';
  eval('(' + globalFunc1.toString() + ')()');
}
```

**Edit:**

I am actually looking for some features from Javascript which are similar to `Function.prototype.bind`, `.call` or `.apply` to achieve what I wanted to do.

To elaborate what I am doing:

```
function checker() {
  if (someVar == 'some value') { 
    /* ... */
  }
}

setTimeout(function() {
  var someVar = 'some value';
  /* ... */
  checker();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: No, it's not possible

Answer (score 2):

You could move `globalFunc1` inside `globalFunc2`, so it has access to the latter's internal variables, but assign it to a global variable to allow it to be invoked from outside:

```
function globalFunc2() {

  window.globalFunc1 = function() {
    console.log(hello);
  };

  var hello = 'hello';
  globalFunc1(); // will print "hello"
}

globalFunc1(); // will print "hello"
```

Here, `globalFunc1` is defined inside `globalFunc2`, and so has access to the variables in its closure, `hello` in this case. However, it itself is a global variable, allowing it to be accessed from outside.

In terms of how you asked the question, you can "access function scope chain from a globally defined function" if (and only if) that globally defined (perhaps one should say "declared" instead) function points to a function **inside the other function's scope**.

Whatever you do, do not do your `eval` thing. What you are essentially doing there is defining (and then immediately executing) the function by lexically copying it in. Instead of doing that, why not just write the function there to start with, as above?

Comment: Thank you for your input! Since `globalFunc2` is sort of a callback and will be executed multiple times, I don't want to define the same function (i.e.: `globalFunc1`) multiple times. I will take your approach for the time being, though. (Question updated accordingly)